# How to give money to a 10 year old niece on joint business venture?

Tags: united-states, children, trusts, long-term

My niece and I came up with a good idea that I think will make some money. I want to compensate her accordingly for what she has done.

I don't want to give her the money now, and I don't want to put it in a college fund. I would like her to be able to access it when she is around 25 years old.

What is the best way to get this to her? If all goes well it would probably be about 10-50k.

Thank you!

Comment: The term [irrevocable trust](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irrevocabletrust.asp) springs to mind, but I've never had anything to do with it and IANAL.

Comment: What are your main concerns? Are you concerned about the legal structure (e.g. a trust) or the financial performance (risk vs. return)?

Comment: Also, why don't you want to put it in a college fund?

Comment: You could write her a check for $15k or hand her cash. You could do this every year with no tax implication for her or you until you have paid her as much as you like. But because you are asking the question, I assume you don't want to do this. What about a cash transaction don't you like?

Comment: @DStanley she might not want to go to college.  Or other relatives might have funded/be funding her college tuition.  Or maybe he thinks college is a rip-off.

Comment: @spuck given the OP says the money is in compensation for business services (given "I want to compensate her accordingly for what she has done." and "on joint business venture?") its probably dubious to try and count it against the 15k gift allowance. Unless there are special rules for minors?

Comment: @Vality: in reality, is anyone going to care? If the poster wanted to do this “by the book”, they would draw up a contract or agreement (which the minor probably couldn’t sign anyway). The tone of the question makes me think that there isn’t any formal agreement in place, but the poster wants to give his niece what he thinks is “fair”.

Comment: Re: *"If all goes well..."* So do you intend to give a set amount of money to your niece in advance, or is the amount of money and timing contingent on some level of the idea's success in the future? I think the answer is important with respect to structuring the eventual reward, unless you're OK with giving the money regardless. And is it money that you wish to award, or some kind of equity in the eventual business that's *worth* a designated amount of money at the time of reward?

Comment: I don't see why you want to tie up the money in a trust for 15 years. If she's had one good idea, she's likely to have more. The profit from this venture could be the seed money for the next.

Comment: @DStanley Her parents have plenty of money to spend on her college. I don't want it to be a gift to them, I want it to be special for her when she needs it for a car or house. The reason I do not want to give it to her right away is because I know what kind of things a teenagers might spend money on.  I know this is not really my business, I just know if the money I gave her somehow spurred a destructive addiction( there is zero indication she is this type of girl) It would be hard for me to live with myself

Comment: @Chris W. Rea It is all contingent on success of the product. Basically she has helped me with a personal idea I had that is geared towards children. She has been very helpful on giving me insight into what kids are looking for. I potentially see her getting 12.5% of revenue, someone else 12.5%, me 25%  ( I am doing the vast majority of the work and connection building) and a non profit getting 50%(maybe that's too high?)

Comment: Maybe instead I would try to structure it 25% to all four, or something like 34% me, 22% to other three

Comment: In terms of actual time spent it would be me by far the most, other partner the second, niece the third, and the non profit providing invaluable connections and product entry

Comment: @Trey fair enough, but keep in mind that college-savings gifts can have significant tax advantages. But perhaps her parents are planning on that tax break, too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a [UTMA](https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/what-is-utma.aspx):

> One common form of custodial account is known by the acronym UTMA. UTMA stands for the Uniform Transfers to Minors Act, which is the legal provision in many states that authorizes a custodian to hold assets on behalf of a minor child until the child reaches the age of majority -- typically either 18 or 21. Although the custodian has legal possession of the minor's assets in a UTMA account, UTMA also imposes a fiduciary duty on the custodian to hold the assets on the minor's behalf. In addition, for tax purposes, the account is treated as the minor's, rather than as the custodian's, which has its advantages.

This does not meet your criteria for being 25 years old.

An [irrevocable trust](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irrevocabletrust.asp) may allow you to enforce that age restriction:

> An irrevocable trust is a type of trust where its terms cannot be modified, amended or terminated without the permission of the grantor's named beneficiary or beneficiaries. The grantor, having effectively transferred all ownership of assets into the trust, legally removes all of their rights of ownership to the assets and the trust.